# In c++, how do I properly use setprecision in this case? (It keeps on rounding off my results)

Tags: c++

**My main goal for the code is to get input from user, put it inside an array that has a size of 10, identify the lowest element in the array given by the user, print the sum of all elements in the array, remove the lowest number and compute the average of the remaining elements inside the array.** My main problem is when I try to print the average of the remaining 9 numbers (lowest number is removed), the result is almost always rounded off or it automatically adds 5.00 to the result.

i used the variable ave to print the average of the remaining 9 numbers, and used setprecision(2) to make the decimal places into 2 (0.00). How do I fix this? thank you!

the result when you try to run the code is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE69M.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int dim=10;
int list[dim];
int i;  
int sum;
int newsum;
double ave;

int smallest = 0;
int temp;


cout<<"enter number: "<<endl; // takes input
for(int i = 0; i<dim; i++)
{
    cout<<"loc["<<i<<"] ";
    cin>>list[i];
}

smallest = list[0];

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) // gets the lowest num
{
    temp = list[i];
    if (temp < smallest) 
    {
        smallest = temp;
    }
}

cout<<"lowest numb is: "<<smallest<<endl; // displays the lowest num
 // tries to replace the element from the list[] array with the value of 0



    
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) // solves the sum of all numbers
{
    sum+=list[i];

}
cout<< fixed << showpoint;
cout<< setprecision(2); // tells the code to print value in 2 decimal places (0.00)
ave = ((sum - smallest)/9); //computes the average with total minus lowest element in array
cout<<"sum is: "<<sum<<endl; 
cout<<"average is: "<< ave << endl; // displays values
```

}

Comment: `int dim=10; int list[dim];` -- This is not valid C++.  The `dim` must be a `const int`, not just an `int`.  Second: `for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)` -- Ask yourself what happens on the last iteration of that loop and `list[i]`.  What is the value of `i`?  Any loop that uses `<=` as a condition will be looked at as faulty.

Answer (score 0):

1. `for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)` also checks `list[10]`, which is undefined and results in some unpredictable value.
   That 11th element value may result as the smallest element, and thus cause wrong results.
2. `sum` should be initialized to `0`, leaving it uninitialised will also be undefined and cause errors.
3. `setprecision(N)` means to use `N` digits total, not just after the  decimal separator:
   https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/
   It will skip any trailing zeroes, indeed unless you also use `std::fixed`.